# sed match on one line and change another one

Tags: sed

I want to go through a file (in this case it is apache2.conf), search for a line () that marks the beginning of a section and change another line (AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All) within that section.

The line I want to change may or may not be the line next to the begining of the section, but I only want to change it's first occurence.

Here is an exemple from apache2.conf:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>             <= this is the begining of the section
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None        <= this is the line I want to change
        Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#       AllowOverride None
#       Require all granted
#</Directory>
```

With the help of a friend I came to this:

`sed '/"<Directory \/var\/www\/>"/,$ {s/"AllowOverride None"/"AllowOverride All"/ }' apache2.conf`

but the fact is that it doesn't work.
I was expecting that `AllowOverride None` would be `AllowOverride All` after going through sed.

Is there any solution ? What I'm I doing wrong ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As a rule, instead of saying "this is what it should do, but it doesn't work", it is better to say "this is what it should do, but this is what it does".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `sed` command is quite close. First you should not include any double quote in it:

```
sed '/<Directory \/var\/www\/>/,$ {
        s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/
}' apache2.conf
```

The problem now is that it will also change the `AllowOverride None` in the last section that is commented out, and you "only want to change it's first occurence".

Just end your block at the first "AllowOverride None" occurrence:

```
sed '/<Directory \/var\/www\/>/,/AllowOverride None/ {
        s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/
}' apache2.conf
```